# Convert list to Array2D

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I'm trying to convert a single list to a multi-dimensional Array2D. Basically go from `[1; 2; 3]` to `[[1; 2; 3]]`. I can't just use `List.toArray` as I'm using an API function which takes an `int[,]` as one of its inputs.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I mean better way than: `let convToArray2D (lst: 'T list) = Array2D.init 1 lst.Length (fun _ j -> List.nth lst j)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just nest the list within another list:

```
array2D [[1; 2; 3]]

> val it : int [,] = [[1; 2; 3]]
```

Comment: That function _in general_ is pretty useful.